# How does Yahoo handle input considering you cannot modify its frontend to affect the email you send?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, validation, input, yahoo-mail

I was doing some research with emails and I believe I found an interesting technology, perhaps something very powerful from a cyber-security perspective.

If you open a Yahoo email in Google Chrome and click "Forward", you can do so with the javascript console.

[image]

You get the element by its classname or id and use the .click(), for instance after you open an email write this in your console

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("r_P u_b C_Z2aVTcY b_0 P_0 M_0 H_6Nds A_6EqO y_Z2hYGcu I_T C4_Z29WjXl ir3_1JO2M7 it3_dBP")[2];
x.click();
```

However there is no way to add your input programmatically and it makes me wondering how this is even possible.

[image]

In the image above, you can click on the "To" parameter and it will work. However ***THERE IS NO WAY*** to set your input from the javascript console in Google Chrome and then press the Send Button because it will simply not work. Don't believe me? Try it.

I noticed that one of the inputs has a "value" attribute which changes to the email you write as seen in the next picture

[image]

I did everything to set the right input, including the following commands:

```
let x = document.querySelectorAll('[id=message-to-field]')[0]
x.setAttribute("value","fakeemail@yahoo.com");
```

The email sets up correctly however when I click "Send" I get the error that no email was set

[image]

*Other things I tried worth mentioning*

- Set up the email with a **;** at the end like fakeemail@yahoo.com;
- `x.value = "fakeemail@yahoo.com"; // this sets the internal value, not the value attribute`
- `x.parentElement.innerText = "fakeemail@yahoo.com";`

I now have two questions:

1. How is this possible in terms of technology? Does Yahoo constantly control client-side inputs and at what expense (e.g resources, loading time, etc.) ?
2. Assuming there is a way, how can we set up the email input using the Javascript console in Google Chrome?

Comment: Seems like Yahoo & Outlook use the same technology. So far I couldn't accomplish that on Outlook & Yahoo but I could do it on Gmail. I'm interested in the answer